# HTML, Attributes and Order

Tags: html

Please consider the following HTML code fragment:

```
<body bgcolor = "red" text="black">
```

In this case, bgcolor and text are attributes of the tag body. I claim that the order the attributes appear in, does not matter. Do I have that right?

I understand that this can be done via CSS and that is the preferred way of doing it, but I am trying to understand the fine point of HTML. I also want to understand if the order of the attributes matters for any tags.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: it's exactly like describing a car, if I say that it is a red BMW or a BMW that is red, then just like the parameters in the body tag, it means the exact same thing.

Comment: A bit off-topic from the question at hand, but `bgcolor` and `text` were long deprecated even in 2017. If someone's teaching you to do that instead of using CSS for styling, they're not doing a very good job.

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't really matter what order you put attributes in an HTML tag, but you carefully maintain a consistent pattern for readability/debugging reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`bgcolor` and `text` don't interfere with each other so the order is not important.

In general, the order of html attributes is not important.